# Setting object values in a for loop and then pushing to array causes all final array items to have the same values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have a simple function that basically takes an object as a parameter, adds a value and then pushes it to an array.

```js
var objectFruits = {
  name: 'apple'
}

var fruits = []

function pushToArray(parameters) {
  var newObject;
  newObject = Object.assign({}, parameters)

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newObject.value = i
    fruits.push(newObject)
    console.log(newObject)
  }
}

pushToArray(objectFruits)

console.log(fruits)
```

This gives me a result of:

```
0: {name: "apple", value: 2}
1: {name: "apple", value: 2}
2: {name: "apple", value: 2}
```

Where as it should be:

```
0: {name: "apple", value: 0}
1: {name: "apple", value: 1}
2: {name: "apple", value: 2}
```

Why is it that the final array `fruits` show that each item's `value` is `2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the value of same object in every iteration of the loop, you need to create a new object.

Just put this line

```
newObject = Object.assign({}, parameters)
```

inside the for-loop

**Demo**

```js
var objectFruits = {
  name: 'apple'
};
var fruits = [];

function pushToArray(parameters) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, parameters)
    newObject.value = i
    fruits.push(newObject);
  }
}

pushToArray(objectFruits);

console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is your trying to modify the value of the same object `newObject`. In the end of the loop all the value of `newObject` is updated with last value.

You should move `let newObject = Object.assign({},parameters);` inside for loop, so that you have new object reference for each object and here you can add different `value` value.

```js
var objectFruits = {
 name:'apple' 
}

var fruits = []

function pushToArray(parameters) {
  //var newObject = Object.assign({},parameters);

  for( var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    let newObject = Object.assign({},parameters);
    newObject.value = i;
    fruits.push(newObject);
    console.log(newObject);
  }
}

pushToArray(objectFruits)

console.log(fruits)
```