# Pushing dynamic object to array updates all objects in the resulting array

Tags: javascript

Having issues getting unique objects where all props are the same except one of them. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823535/setting-object-values-in-a-for-loop-and-then-pushing-to-array-causes-all-final-a) but the solution there doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my source snippet:

```js
const countryData = countryIds.map(countryId => {
    let countryObject = Object.assign({}, baseObject);
    countryObject.cells['Country ID'] = countryId;
    console.log(countryObject)
    allData.push(countryObject);
})
```

My result:

```json
          {
        cells: {
          'Customer Name': [Object],
          'Assessment Level': [Object],
          Function: [Object],
          Assessment: [Object],
          'Country ID': '961558361'
        }
      },
      {
        cells: {
          'Customer Name': [Object],
          'Assessment Level': [Object],
          Function: [Object],
          Assessment: [Object],
          'Country ID': '961558361'
        }
      }....
```

What I'd expect to see:

```json
    {
        cells: {
          'Customer Name': [Object],
          'Assessment Level': [Object],
          Function: [Object],
          Assessment: [Object],
          'Country ID': '[UNIQUE ID]'
        }
      },
      {
        cells: {
          'Customer Name': [Object],
          'Assessment Level': [Object],
          Function: [Object],
          Assessment: [Object],
          'Country ID': '[UNIQUE ID]'
        }
      }....
```

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: How to group together 2 objects with same Country ID ?

Comment: Not grouping per se. I'm trying to build a large request body to update a table. For context, I'm iterating through multiple levels of hierarchy, where each level has "assessments" that need to be created N number of times depending on how many unique IDs there are at that level. 

So I'm first mapping the assessments themselves (which have a level definition (i.e. 'Customer', 'Country', etc.), and IF it's 'Country' I map the country IDs and build unique 'cells' objects for each country ID / assessment. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution elsewhere. Adding here for reference. Instead of using `Object.assign()`, I need to use `structuredClone()` to replicate the source object (rather than making a shallow copy). Once replicated I can add/update properties as needed.